# Iterate a nested record/dictionary OCaml

Tags: ocaml, record

Sorry for asking a ridiculous question but I am a total beginner in OCaml.

I have two types:

```
type other = A | B
type someType = {a:string ; b:string ; c:other ; d:someType array}
```

How could I iterate through a record and get all occurrences of a key?

Since I do not know how deep the structure goes, I cannot figure out how many times I have to loop through each array to get the key.

```
let test = 
  {a = "a"; b = "b"; c = B;
   d =
    [|{a = "aa"; b = "bb"; c = A;
       d =
        [|{a = "aaa"; b = "bbb"; c = A;
           d =
            [|{a = "aaaa"; b = "bbbb"; c = A; d = [||]};
              {a = "aaaaa"; b = "bbbbb"; c = B; d = [||]}|]}|]}|]}
```

I want to count all a keys and sort them by c key. In this example I have 5 a keys, 2 of type B and 3 of type A. I want to return them as int * int = (3, 2)

Comment: Your code isn't syntactically valid, although I can reasonably guess at what it's intended to be. Could you also be a bit more concrete? What is an example of expected input and output?

Comment: @glennsl Let's say I have a record: `let test = {a="a";b="b";c=B;d=[|{a="aa";b="bb";c=A;d=[|{a="aaa";b="bbb";c=A;d=[|{a="aaaa";b="bbbb";c=A;d=[||]};{a="aaaaa";b="bbbbb";c=B;d=[||]};|]};|]};|]};`  I want to count all a keys and sort them by c key. In this example I have 5 a keys, 2 of type B and 3 of type A. I want to return them as int * int = (3, 2)

Comment: You should try to break it down into smaller sub-problems. How would you do what you want with just one level? How would you apply that same operation to nested levels? And how would you decide when to stop? How would you track the counts?

Answer (score 2):

Records in OCaml are not like dictionaries in Python, so you can't really iterate over them. A record is more like a class, in the sense that it is a type not a value.

A counterpart of the python dictionary is the map data structure. Since OCaml is a statically typed language it has a separate data type per each key/value types. You can use [Map.Make](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.Make.html) to define a map structure for the given key type, e.g.,

```
module Strings = Map.Make(String)
```

Now we can create a sample dictionary,

```
let family = Strings.of_seq @@ List.to_seq [
    "Alice", 30;
    "Bob", 32;
    "Charlie", 8;
    "Daniel", 12;
  ]
```

And to iterate we can use the [Strings.iter](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.Make.html#VALiter) function,

```
let () = family |> Strings.iter (fun name age ->
    Format.printf "%s is %d years old\n" name age)
```

Or, since OCaml is a curried language, just

```
let () = family |> Strings.iter (Format.printf "%s is %d years old\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the base condition: no nesting at all. The array in field `d` is empty. If field `c` is `A`, then you would return `(1, 0)`. Otherwise if it's `B`, `(0, 1)`.

That's simple.

```
let rec count_c_keys {c; d; _} =
  match c, d with
  | A, [||] -> (1, 0)
  | B, [||] -> (0, 1)
```

But what if `d` isn't an empty array? Then we'd want to map our function over that array.

```
d |> Array.map count_c_keys
```

But that will give us an array of tuples. How can we make an array of tuples into a tuple that we can add to either `(1, 0)` or `(0, 1)`?

Array.fold_left will work nicely.

```
let sum_2tuples_array =
  let add_tuples (a, b) (c, d) = (a + c, b + d) in 
  Array.fold_left add_tuples (0, 0)
```

Now, we can turn that `someType array` into a `(int * int) array` and from there into a `int * int` tuple. Once we've done that, with some pattern-matching, it's trivial to add one to either element depending on whether `A` or `B` has been encountered at field `c`.

```
let rec count_c_keys {c; d; _} =
  let sum_2tuples_array = 
    let add_tuples (a, b) (c, d) = (a + c, b + d) in
    Array.fold_left add_tuples (0, 0) 
  in
  match c, d with
  | A, [||] -> (1, 0)
  | B, [||] -> (0, 1)
  | A, _ -> 
    let (a_s, b_s) = d 
      |> Array.map count_c_keys 
      |> sum_2tuples_array 
    in
    (1 + a_s, b_s)
  | B, _ -> 
    let (a_s, b_s) = d 
      |> Array.map count_c_keys 
      |> sum_2tuples_array 
    in
    (a_s, 1 + b_s)
```

```
utop # count_c_keys test;;
- : int * int = (3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand right, your problem lies in the recursive structure.

Consequently this is a recursive problem.
The comment from @glennsl gives you some questions that can lead to your solution.

How would you do for the innermost element of type `someType` ?
This element is characterised by a special value for `d` ?

As an example, I will use list instead of array. If I try to get all `x` in

```
type spList = {x:xType ; l:spList list};;
```

I would consider that an innermost element is one element that have an empty list for `l`. In this case, I will only take the `x` as a lone `xType`.

```
getX : spList -> x list
getX s = if ( s.l = [] ) then [ x ] else ... (* something is missing *)
```

Then I will wondering what's look like a more general case, when `l` is a non-empty list. It will be a list of spList. So a function that have the type `spList list` to `x list list` will help me. This is fantastic since I know that I can that `map` a function from `a` to `b` to obtain a function from `a list` to `b list`.

```
getXs : spList list -> x list list
getXs = map getX
```

And finally I can complete my function `getX`

```
getX s = if ( s.l = [] ) 
         then [x]                           (* the singleton made of x *) 
         else let k = [x] in
              let r = concat (getXs s.l) in (* get all the inner `x` *)
              append k r
```

Now you can see that `[x] = append [x] (concat [])` and `getXs [] = []` so this can be shrink to

```
getX = let k = [x] in                (* this level  *)
       let r = concat (getXs s.l) in (* inner level *)
       append k r                    (* the result  *)
```

For your case, you will have to figure what is a `map` for your array, how you will be able to `concat`enate them and to `append` two arrays. But the principle is the same.

**Be aware** that my solution is naive. Using recursive append is usually a bad idea. Optimizing `getX` is not difficult but is another step.